# How to include jars under lib in multi-project sbt setup?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project that is similar to the [sbt-multi-project-example](https://github.com/pbassiner/sbt-multi-project-example) one. The only difference is that I have two already compiled jar dependencies inside a `lib/` folder on root folder.

On a single-project sbt setup it automatically collects those jars and use them to compile my project, but in this case it is not being collected by the sub-projects.

Only one of my sub-projects require those jars.

Where should I put those jars and how should I setup `build.sbt` to recognize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the jars in a `lib/` folder in the sub-project that requires them.

Comment: Like in `my-project/sub-project-1/lib/dependency.jar`? Like that it is not being recognized

Comment: Oh no I'm sorry, sbt hadn't finished refreshing. It works like a charm :)